# Mark enum from referenced dll with FlagsAttribute

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, vb6, enums, interop

In .Net I can (and should) apply the `FlagsAttribute` to enums that are used as bitmask. This way I can use the `HasFlag()`-method and ReSharper doesn't get angry if I do bitwise operations on them.

In a project I have to use an enum from a dll written in vb6 which of course does not have the `FlagsAttribute`. (I have seen the code, the values are bit flags.)

Eventhough VisualStudio marks it as red in code whenever I use `.HasFlag()`, it compiles and runs just fine. And I can "disable" the ReSharper warning on bitwise operations by always casting the enum to int (or suppress it with a comment, …)

Yet I wonder if there is a somewhat cleaner approach like marking the enum as flags once?

Comment: I doubt MIDL even accepts a "flags" attribute on an enum so this isn't really a VB6 issue: C++, etc. should be the same.  Maybe somebody can find one?  If so you could create a separate typelib based on the one in the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mark an external dependency - if you have a `dll`, whatever its source, you can't simply change its internals (well, you *can*, but that would require rewriting the binary).

One option is to write your *own* flags enumeration and a mapper between the VB6 one and yours and simply use your version in your code and simply ignore the issues in the mapping layer.

Comment: Not what I hoped to hear, but kind of what I expected. Thanks.

Comment: The mapping could even be at compile time by just giving them the same values, or using the imported enum values directly.